# How to avoid code duplication inside two methods?

Tags: c#

I have two identical methods, but one of them have return statement inside `try catch`

```
public void A(Guid agentId)
{
     var agent = _agentsProvider.GetAgentById(agentId);
     var updateCompletionSource = C(agentId);
     try
     {
         var cacheEntry = UpdateAgentMetadataCacheEntry(agent, true, false);
         updateCompletionSource.SetResult(cacheEntry);
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
         updateCompletionSource.SetException(e);
     }
}

private Entry B(IAgent agent)
{
     var updateCompletionSource = C(agent.Id);
     try
     {
          var cacheEntry = UpdateAgentMetadataCacheEntry(agent, false, false);
          updateCompletionSource.SetResult(cacheEntry);
          return cacheEntry;
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
          updateCompletionSource.SetException(e);
          return GetPreviousCacheEntry();
      }
}
```

How to collect identical part and create new method with this part?

Comment: I don't understand your question, what is wrong with the code you have here? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You Should refactor your code and Call A Inside of B where B extends the catch sentence of A, you should throw the error to be catched at an upper level (B mehtod)

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, this code wouldn't compile at all. You refer to `agent` in `A` but it doesn't exist in `A`, only in `B`. Is that line in `A` supposed to be `var cacheEntry = UpdateAgentMetadataCacheEntry(agent.Id, true, false);` ??

Comment: I have this variable but decided not to show. Its no so important

Comment: @ivan_petrushenko it's very confusing if you don't show it.

Comment: @ivan_petrushenko thanks, it makes much more sense now - that missing line of code is one of the reason at least two answers below received downvotes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unless `GetPreviousCacheEntry` could have problematic side-effects, it seems to me that you don't need method `A` at all.

Just call method `B` and ignore the return value if you're not interested in it.

As noted in comments, the methods *aren't* identical other than the return statements though - because they use a different second argument for `UpdateAgentMetadataCacheEntry`, and they have different parameters too (one has a `Guid` and one has an `Agent`). You could refactor this into:

```
private Entry B(IAgent agent, bool foo)
{
     var updateCompletionSource = C(agent.Id);
     try
     {
          var cacheEntry = UpdateAgentMetadataCacheEntry(agent, foo, false);
          updateCompletionSource.SetResult(cacheEntry);
          return cacheEntry;
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
          updateCompletionSource.SetException(e);
          return GetPreviousCacheEntry();
      }
}
```

... with a meaningful name for `foo`, obviously. I'll assume the difference in parameter type isn't a problem in reality.

Comment: `UpdateAgentMetadataCacheEntry` has different parameter values in each method

Comment: @user1666620 Just pass a bool as parameter?

Comment: @user1666620: Whoops, I hadn't seen that. Will edit.

Comment: @user1666620: In that case it seems the signature to `A` is the only one that's actually required.  Though another scan through the code shows that `A()` currently won't even compile, since it tries to use the variable `agent` which it doesn't have.

Comment: @David I have this variable but decided not to show. Its no so important

Comment: @ivan_petrushenko tbh you really ought to show where `agent` is coming from in your method `A` because it is very confusing,

Comment: @ivan_petrushenko: It *is* important when you give an example claiming that two methods are identical apart from a return statement, when there are actually other differences. Even with the edit, that's the case.

Comment: @JonSkeet Sorry, I will be more clear in the next time. But you already solved my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Like Jon said, you don't need method A. Just add another parameter for boolean value.

```
public void A(Guid agentId)
{
    var agent = _agentsProvider.GetAgentById(agentId);
    AnotherA(agent, true);
}

private Entry B(IAgent agent)
{
    return AnotherA(agent, false);
}

private Entry AnotherA(IAgent agent, bool a)
{
    try
    {
         var cacheEntry = UpdateAgentMetadataCacheEntry(agent, a, false);
         updateCompletionSource.SetResult(cacheEntry);
         return cacheEntry;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        updateCompletionSource.SetException(e);
        return GetPreviousCacheEntry();
    }
}
```

Comment: your method `AnotherA` is using an object that doesn't exist, so it won't compile.

Comment: Got the typo. Changed "agent" to "agentId."

Comment: it's still kind of wrong in that `UpdateAgentMetadataCacheEntry` accepts an object `agent`, not a guid.

Comment: I see. That makes it more obvious the method A isn't needed.

Comment: the exception handling do different things in `A` and `B` in the OP's question.

Comment: The exception handler in B will return GetPreviousCacheEntry() which will get ignored.